# Beginner with jQuery, background doesn't change back

Tags: jquery

So, I tried to create a normal menu. 
HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">hompeage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

(Grey background is necessary in this case). 
Adding to this menu, I tried to create an `.each()` function that changes the `border-top-color` and the `background`of each (a) tag. 
**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tesunucubi/edit?html,css,js,output)** 
 
But I have a problem - hovering the menu from bottom to the top (or from the right to the left if you're on full screen) pretty quickly in a row marks the whole other (a) tags in their background. 
[image] 
jQuery code (even though it appears in the JSBin demo, I put it here to make it more comfortable):

```
var bgcolors = ['#000055', '#4c4c00', '#b27300', '#660000'];



var a = $("li a");


setInterval(function(){  
    a.each(function(index) {
    var current = $(this);
    current.css("border-top-color", bgcolors[index]);
        if($(this).is(":hover")) {
           $(this).css("background", bgcolors[index]);
        }
        else {
           $(this).css("background", "");
        }
    });
}, 200);
```

- I'm pretty beginner with this so please don't be negative and dislike me, I'm still learning it out. 
   Thank you guys.

Edit: changed the code, wasn't the right one.

Edit2: **Solved** 
Used `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` events. So simple.

```
var colors = ['#000055', '#4c4c00', '#b27300', '#660000'];

var a = $("li a");

a.each(
    function(index) {
        var current = $(this);
        current.css("border-top-color", colors[index]);
        $(this).mouseenter(
        function(){
            $(this).css("background", colors[index]);
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(
        function(){
            $(this).css("background", "");
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 changing the background and border-top-color of each (a) tag by jQuery. there's a bug when i hover the (a) tags from right to left

Comment: Use mouseenter and mousleave events ... or combined in jQuery `hover()`. Using an interval timer is not the normal approach to this. Can slo do it with css alone

Comment: What is "bug" ? Tried utilizing `css` ?

Comment: You are basically employing a very odd and overly complicated way to achieve this effect, what you want to do is utilize mouseenter and mouseleave events (https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ for examples) or even better, just do it with pure css using the :hover selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hover()` for handling `hover` event

```js
var bgcolors = ['#000055', '#4c4c00', '#b27300', '#660000'],
  colors = ['#b27300', '#660000', '#000055', '#4c4c00'];

$("li a").hover(
  function() {
    var current = $(this),
      index = $(this).parent().index();
    current.css({
      "background": bgcolors[index],
      "color": colors[index],
      "border-top-color": bgcolors[index]
    });
  },
  function() {
    var current = $(this),
      index = $(this).parent().index();
    current.css({
      "background": "",
      "color": "",
      "border-top-color": ""
    });
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
ul li {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 130px;
}
li a {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">hompeage</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `css` `:nth-of-type()` , `:hover` pseudo classes

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

ul li {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 130px;
}

li a {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(1) a:hover {
  border-top-color: #000055;
  background: #000055;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2) a:hover {
  border-top-color: #4c4c00;
  background: #4c4c00;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(3) a:hover {
  border-top-color: #b27300;
  background: #b27300;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(4) a:hover {
  border-top-color: #660000;
  background: #660000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">hompeage</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i know this option, but i waned to use jQuery

Comment: Hahaha http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif Now you are in the jQuery trap... CSS is 1000 times better for this job!

Comment: @rolory see? ^^^^

Comment: Using a quick search query "beginner" to see some noob questions @rolory

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent ouch ?